# Windows 10 UWP Pin to start confirmation dialog not hiding

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10, uwp-xaml

I have created a Radio application in Win 10 UWP and I have initiated a pinning of secondary tile using `PinTileData.RequestCreateAsync()` . It will create a confirmation popup for pinning. I want to dismiss that popup from code when using deeplink from another app. Is there any way to hide the popup from code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your `PinTileData.RequestCreateAsync()` is. I'd suppose you are using [SecondaryTile.RequestCreateAsync() method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/br242213.aspx) to pin the secondary tile. As we can see in the document, this method

> Displays the **Pin to Start** flyout, through which the user can confirm that they want to create the secondary tile, which in turn creates the tile.

So the confirmation dialog is by design, every pin to the Start screen is subject to user consent. And for now there is no way to hide the dialog from code. However, on Windows Mobile, when requesting to pin a secondary tile, the request is now done without any user or system interaction.

If you do want to pin a secondary tile without user consent, please feel free to  ask for this feature on [**UserVoice**](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform?query=pin%20secondary%20tile%20without%20user%20consent) and also the Windows Feedback Hub app.